# What write patterns are "flash-friendly"?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, rewrite

Assume we are talking about a run-of-the-mill USB flash drive (which may or may not do wear leveling) and a "dumb" filesystem that isn't especially optimized for flash memory (like FAT32, etc.) The drive likely does not have TRIM support.

Since flash drive blocks only have a limited number of rewrites, it would make sense to try to minimize as many rewrites as possible. Now if I were to create some files A, B, and C then repeatedly modify files in-place, would this wear the drive more than just adding B', C', etc. and eventually removing the originals when I run out of space?

Am I prematurely optimizing or is there a grain of truth in there?

(Note: this is not about what the *drive or OS* does internally. This is about how a *user* should use it)

Comment: To clarify, is your question "Does modifying an in-place file not count as a write in regards to the write-life of flash storage?"

Comment: It's more of the opposite, "does avoiding in-place modification generally avoid wear?"

Comment: Flash media is cheap and far more resilient than it used to be. Just use the drive and dint worry about wear.

Comment: I think you'll find that you're not really going to make things any better. I found this article on CNET that basically says, don't stress about it unless you're writing something like 50GB/day to the drive. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-ssds-solid-state-drives-work-increase-lifespan/

Comment: What happens when it's time to delete the redundant files?  You need to go through GBs of files to identify what to delete.  You also need to keep track of free and used space, and reconstruct what to delete after the fact rather than allowing automatic timely deletion.  If you wait too long, your actual work may be delayed due to insufficient space.  It sounds like you want to use your own time and energy to perform the functions of the controller chip on a cheap drive.  (cont'd)

Comment: That doesn't help you get your own work done, it adds work for you in order to potentially get a little more life out of a cheap device.  Pennies worth of silicon, intended to make your life easier, would be delegating its work to you so you can do its job many orders of magnitude slower.  Humans as inferior slaves to silicon masters -- sounds like a scifi horror movie.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All USB drives have a microcontroller that takes incoming USB requests and translates them to actions consistent with the actual storage on the USB device.

In the case of USB drives that have NAND flash, the firmware/microcontroller on these devices likely (hopefully) implements a FTL that does wear leveling.

Unfortunately, you cannot know what that microcontroller is doing exactly without having the source code to any firmware and full knowledge of it's small hardware platform on that USB flash drive.

There is no such thing as a standard hardware, firmware or software platform for USB flash drives, so you can't rely on any sort of standards to help you predict exactly what the firmware might be doing with incoming USB requests without intimate knowledge of the microcontroller, NAND flash hardware, and firmware in question.

> this is not about what the drive or OS does internally.

I know, but without that internal knowledge you can't modify your write behavior meaningfully.  Especially since there's various microcontrollers, firmwares, and NAND flash chips, what might have any sort of effect on one flash drive may not work on a different flash drive.

---

> a "dumb" filesystem that isn't especially optimized for flash memory

Filesystems "optimized for flash memory" require direct access to the flash hardware so they can issue erase commands to the flash themselves.  Talking to a device via USB, SATA, SCSI bus via mass storage commands is not direct access.

Probably the easiest situation where you can experience this is Linux-based consumer-level routers - the underlying Linux OS is on and has access to a 4MB, 8MB, 16MB or similar flash chip and can talk to it and manage it directly.  Android phones are similar.

You can't issue an erase command on USB or SATA mass storage devices other than TRIM (and that's just a request to device firmware, not a direct command to flash chips), those standards are meant for hard drives and not flash hardware.

> Now if I were to create some files A, B, and C then repeatedly modify files in-place, would this wear the drive more than just adding B', C', etc.

Flash chips are read and written in pages.  They are erased in sets of pages that Linux projects call "eraseblocks".  (This is very different than mechanical hard drives).

Flash-based storage devices implement an FTL - a flash translation layer.  What this is: They maintain an internal table that maps OS-visible "blocks" to firmware-visible flash pages (PBA to LBA), and they will also keep track of which "eraseblocks" are ready for new data.  Incoming writes will not go to a flash page only based on the incoming block number, but wherever the firmware deems is a good spot - and the firmware will update its internal PBA to LBA table to find it when it's needed next.

Good firmwares will try to redirect writes to eraseblocks with erased pages for performance reasons, and they will swap blocks in the background to try to make it so that erasing is not needed before writing.  When drives get full, it's less likely this can be done, and performance will suffer.

You can then assume that writes, even if the same file and "block" from the OS point of view, do not go to the same place on the flash.  So you gain nothing by worrying about modifying files in place.

---

The moral of the story: Don't worry about it.  Treat it like a normal hard drive, and keep backups.  Crappy flash drives will die earlier than good ones.